# For loop outputting columns and rows using bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to replicate this structure with bootstrap:

```
 <div class="col-sm-3 right-border">
            <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">&nbsp;</div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 right-border">
            <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">&nbsp;</div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 right-border">
            <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">&nbsp;</div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 right-border">
            <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">&nbsp;</div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Item</a>
        </div>
```

Using this code:

```
 <?php
            $count = 0;
            $maxColumns = 4;

            $myArray = @['Item', 'Item', 'Item', 'Item', 'Item', 'Item', 'Item', 'Item', 'Item', 'Item', 'Item', 'Item', 'Item', 'Item', 'Item', 'Item'];


            foreach($myArray as $item) {
                echo "<div class='col-sm-3 right-border'>";
                echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block\" role=\"button\">";
                echo 'Item';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                $i++;
                if ($i % $maxColumns == 0) {echo '</div><div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">&nbsp;</div>';}
            }

        ?>
```

I have tried using a for loop too but it always spits out garbage.

Most tutorials have suggested using a row, outputting 4 columns and then starting a new row. Surely there is away to output 1 column  with four items.

Using rows then adding 4 items doesn't give the visual result.

Comment: do you know ahead of time how many items you will have? or you always want 4 columns no matter how many items?

Comment: I always want 4 columns. I want the columns to have an equal number of buttons, and if there are not an even number, just keep filling up the columns until they are evenly distributed.

Comment: Suppose your items are "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H". Do you want A,B,C,D all in the first column? Or going across in the same row?

Comment: If the items are "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N" the last column would only have M,N. Or if "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q" The first column would have 5 items ending in Q.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option here would be to split your array in to sub arrays. I grabbed the `partition` function from http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

```
<?php

    function partition( $list, $p ) {
        $listlen = count( $list );
        $partlen = floor( $listlen / $p );
        $partrem = $listlen % $p;
        $partition = array();
        $mark = 0;
        for ($px = 0; $px < $p; $px++) {
            $incr = ($px < $partrem) ? $partlen + 1 : $partlen;
            $partition[$px] = array_slice( $list, $mark, $incr );
            $mark += $incr;
        }
        return $partition;
    }

    $maxColumns = 4;

    $myArray = @['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N'];
    $cols = partition($myArray, $maxColumns);


    foreach($cols as $col) {
        echo "<div class='col-sm-3 right-border'>";
        echo "<div class='hidden-md-lg'>&nbsp;</div>";

        foreach($col as $item) {
            echo "<a href='#' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block' role='button'>$item</a>";
        }

        echo '</div>';
    }

?>
```